# mysql stored function parameter syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

What is wrong with this syntax?

mysql 5.5, phpmyadmin 3.4

```
delimiter ;;
create procedure foo(a text, b int, c text)
begin
select * from table_a where attribute1 like %a% 
and attribute2 = b
and attribute3 like %c%
end
;;
```

phpmyadmin tells me wrong syntax at line 1, but it doesn't seem to work, no matter what.

Comment: @AndaIancu Same error, but the double semicolon worked before, i dont think thats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you don't even need to change `DELIMITER` and use `BEGIN ... END` block. Your procedure might look like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo(a TEXT, b INT, c TEXT)
SELECT * 
  FROM table_a 
 WHERE attribute1 LIKE CONCAT('%', a, '%')
   AND attribute2 = b
   AND attribute3 LIKE CONCAT('%', c, '%');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81dab/1)** demo

Comment: This answer generates the LIKE clause with the parameters passed to the procedure, producing a string. Your original %a% was not a valid string.

Answer (score 0):

Missing quotes.

```
delimiter ;;

create procedure foo(a text, b int, c text)
begin
  select * from table_a where attribute1 like concat('%', a,' %') 
  and attribute2 = b
  and attribute3 like concat('%', c,' %');
end;;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I'm looking for text similar to the letter 'a' and 'c'? I want to use parameters.